# CSS Background Image Load Behavior

Tags: css

Say there is a css style declaration to an element which has been set `display:none` (not displayed on screen) and it also has a background image set.

Lets say this element is displayed on an event such as a mouse click. Would the browser load these images even before the element is displayed? Is this load behaviour consistent across browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, browsers I've tested before do not.

if you do want to load the image, try using `background-position: -1000px -1000px` which does work. It won't show the image, but it will be preloaded. However, the element will be in the normal flow, i.e. not hidden.

Comment: i just want to make sure that images which are hidden from the document are not loaded by the browser.So this is ture for major browsers?

Comment: Yes, if a background image is on a hidden element, it won't be shown. However, if you delay hiding an element with JS for example, there's a chance that image will be loaded.

Comment: Chrome seems to load the `display:none` background image anyway

Comment: That's not true for the majority of browsers, as it's said by futtta in another answer

Answer (score 4):

There's not a lot of good info on this topic, so I did some tests on webpagetest.org using [a testpage by Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/tests/hidden-bgimages.php).

It turns out that of all browsers tested, **only Firefox does not load a background-image with display:none**. You can [see the test results on my blog here](http://blog.futtta.be/2012/12/10/do-background-images-lazy-load-with-displaynone/).

Answer (score 2):

It is not loaded automatically but you can use a Javascript trick to preload an image.

```
pic = new Image(); 
pic.src="http://url/imagetoload.png";
```

As a better solution, you may create a div with a negative positioning value (such as left: -1000px) and assign imagetoload.png to its background to load the image.